# WCF: service hosting outside of IIS makes IIS an atrophy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, iis

It appears MS is shooting itself in the leg allowing hosting of WCF services outside of IIS. IIS is relatively simple but yet redundant layer for services from my perspective. Introduction of WCF tremendously simplifies service hosting making IIS an atrophy. So what do you think? I am missing something? Why would I use IIS for WCF services? Because I don't see a reason.

Comment: IIS was the only universal host that Microsoft had at hand - but most WCF experts I know (e.g. Juval Lowy) would argue **never** to use IIS to host production-level WCF services. I always put my production WCF services into self-hosted NT Services.

Comment: @marc_s: +10 if I could.

Comment: @marc_s: can't edit my previous post. Just wanted to mention that NT service is a great way for automatic start and restart in case of crashes. It addresses Pauli's bulletin 2 completely.

Comment: what about memory profiling or request logging, what does WCF provide out of the box? With IIS you get a whole platter of goodies for free for profiling application health and every requests/response.

Comment: @Pauli: if other but HTTP binding is used, what request logging are you referring to? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx gives info on logging options.

Comment: @Pauli: memory profiling is an interesting comment. What goodie do you mean?

Comment: when hosting in IIS you get access to the Asp.Net Health Monitoring features (updated my answer with a link to it)

Answer (score 6):

Hosting inside IIS has its advantages if you want to ie. use the underlying asp.net framework for authentication and authorization. Remember that this requires the `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode` attribute to be set to *Required*. This also gives you access to HttpContext.Current for easy retrieval of post-values, cookies and such.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734710.aspx

- WCF services hosted in IIS are deployed and managed like any other type of IIS application, including ASP.NET applications and ASMX.
- IIS provides process activation, health management, and recycling capabilities to increase the reliability of hosted applications. Accessing the [Health Monitoring Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx) allows you to monitor the status of your web application.
- Like ASP.NET, WCF services hosted in ASP.NET can take advantage of the ASP.NET shared hosting model where multiple applications reside in a common worker process for improved server density and scalability.
- WCF services hosted in IIS use the same dynamic compilation model as ASP.NET 2.0, which simplifies development and deployment of hosted services.

Comment: +1 - and process activation, health management, recycling, shared hosting (multiple apps in common worker process), ...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734710.aspx

Comment: exactly that whitepaper i was looking for! :)

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure? According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738737.aspx WCF provides the same things (see Security section): "... the facilities provided for ASP.NET Web services are also available for WCF services running in ASP.NET compatibility mode"

Comment: but this article just talks about WCF running in ASP.NET compatibility mode which requires IIS.

Comment: please don't downvote without any comments!

Comment: @Pauli: WAS, or Windows Activation Service addresses process activation you mention in bulletin 2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx. In fact, WAS appears to be a superset of IIS functionality but is much more lightweight: http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0701041

Comment: Hosting WCF services in IIS is a kludge and also has a ton of **disadvantages** : dependency on AppPools and recycling which cannot be controlled in any decent way; IIS dictates the server address+port and parts of the service URL; unnecessary *.svc file which messes up your service URL .....

Comment: No offense Pauli, but I doubt people who upvote your response really understand the question. Most of us used IIS for years, its our love-hate baby and I am afraid a lot of people just think there is no other, better, way.

Comment: @Pauli: WAS has nothing to do with IIS. "As a standalone Windows component, WAS is completely separated from the IIS hosting environment and provides a protocol-agnostic activation mechanism" by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Activation_Services

Comment: @marc_s im not saying hosting in IIS is the answer to life the universe and everything, im just pointing out advantages. in the cases you would ever consider IIS for hosting i don't believe you will have problems with App Pool recycling and its merely a choice only for http endpoints, since you don't get the benefits with ASP.NET compability with non-http endpoints. And the .svc, come'on... thats no valid argument since it can't be overcomed in matter of minutes!

Comment: @Schultz9999 youre asking *why* someone would choose to host their WCF service in IIS. I'm listing perfectly valid arguments in favor of IIS, but you make it sound like you have decided already that IIS is evil and any argument in favor of IIS must be invalid. There are many reasons to choose to host in IIS, just like there are many reasons NOT to host in IIS.

Comment: @Pauli: I think I made clear in the question that I don't see a reason to use IIS. If I did, I'd probably asked, what should I use. I admit, I am biased because I don't like IIS - it's heavy and confusing. Since I learned about tomcat and jetty, every time I had to deal with IIS I asked myself when on earth MS would come up with something similar. It took MS forever to comeup with something that doesn't require IIS. And I am happy.

Comment: @Schultz9999 maybe think twice before asking something like *Why would I use IIS for WCF services?* then if you don't want people to answer it.

Comment: @Schultz9999 IMO the question is perfectly valid... just accept points in both favors and maybe come with bullet points yourself why IIS is bad.

Comment: @Pauli: I am not sure I understand bulletin 3. A single process may expose multiple scoped end points (namespace + address + port) of the same or different service interfaces. The service management interface can easily add or remove new end points. So I am not sure I see any IIS advantage here.

Comment: @Schultz9999 re: bulleting 3. This is for multiple applications where IIS can host them inside the same AppPool meaning there is only one w3wp process, even though your running ie. 10 different unrelated applications. This saves memory footprint.

Answer (score 3):

I agree somewhat. Despite the many advantages Pauli mentions in his post (+1 for that), I see several reasons not to choose IIS for WCF:

- **Net* Bindings:** IIS does not natively support non-HTTP/S bindings, such as the (very useful) [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx), [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) and [NetMsmqBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netmsmqbinding.aspx). You can use [Windows Process Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx), but that's not really IIS anymore. Also, older versions of IIS don't have WAS, and so do not support non-HTTP/S bindings at all.
- **Configuration & Deployment:** There is a large configuration overhead to IIS (and WAS) which may not be justified given the deployment scenario of your service.
- **Dependency & Testing:** Using IIS (or WAS) creates an additional dependency on those components. IIS is notorious for only supporting a specific version for each Windows version, and testing your service with many different versions can easily become a burden. An exact version of the .NET Framework can be deployed on a machine and self-hosting ensures that there a minimum number of variables.
- **Ease of Use:** The above mentioned configuration, deployment and dependency issues could prove to be a major and sometimes unnecessary learning curve, especially for non-HTTP/S services.
- **Flexibility:** If you already have a .NET application running as a Windows service, you can just host WCF in it without requiring additional administration effort - if someone's already keeping your service up, then WCF will be up along with it.

Comment: +1 my point in my answer was that the main reason i see to choose IIS is if you need the Asp.Net Compatibility Mode which means only http binding anyway.

Comment: regarding dependency i disagree... IIS is not known for tying into any specific .Net version and running the same WCF service tested for .net 4 should have no problems running on IIS 6, 7 or 7.5 as long as they are configured for .Net 4.

Comment: @Pauli: I'm not really an ASP.NET (or IIS) person, and so I am ignorant of any advantages and disadvantages of the IIS, WCF and ASP.NET trinity. Which is why your answer provides useful insights regarding those things, which I cannot provide. EDIT: Re dependency, a whole layer above you may act different. Concurrency issues and other environment-related issues may surface, even with the same .NET version.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree as of now i.e. IIS 7/7.5 in Windows Server 2008/2008R2. Yes in IIS 6 you had valid reason to host outside IIS (e.g. if you are using net.tcp binding). But IIS gives you better authentication, load balancing, fault tolerance, monitoring etc than possible easily with self hosting. e.g. I never managed to get SSL with client certs working properly with a self hosted service. Or try restricting based on IP address etc. The URL for services ending with .svc is also not valid as of WCF 4.0. Another advantage is most sysadmins are familiar with IIS admin manager and all settings in web.config can be changed easily for operational support from the GUI. Deployment has been made easier, you can basically clone a IIS site from staging to production. With [Appfabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) extensions of IIS you get very detailed monitoring and dashboard of your service calls (like calls/sec, failed calls/sec, avg call duration etc.), service call persistence for workflow hosted services etc. You can also monitor all your IIS sites for a whole company from one central console and I think there is even a integration of appfabric with [SCOM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7E870C9A-0B5B-4CCA-8D8C-42A66B8C9741&displaylang=en)

In a nutshell I believe for enterprise level hosting IIS & Appfabric should be chosen hosting for WCF services.

Comment: You limited yourself to two options - IIS and self-hosting. For HTTP services, sure, IIS is a winner out of these two. However using HTTP for interservice communication is not good because binary bindings are much faster. So if you consider also Windows Service and Windows Activation Services, IIS is no longer such a good idea. And of course they both offer way more than self-hosting.

Comment: I didn't say anything about HTTP except the security scenario. IIS 7 and above can work with WAS for non-HTTP binding and you get all the benefits of Appfabric. Some of us also works to create core enterprise services that are consumed by Java clients and other 3rd parties where maximum interoperability is required and hence binary transport cannot be used.